# Why view function is changing the state?

Tags: solidity

Following piece of code returns the already stored addresses on smart contract.

```
function getAddr(string AddrName) public view returns(address) {
    return addressBook[keccak256(AddrName)];
}
```

When I try to execute function, it execute as a WRITE function instead of READ function. What maybe the problem?

Comment: please share rest of code

Comment: how you tell is doing a 'write' as you said, instead of a 'read'. I can't see any state changes and in remix it works properly with a call